# Bytecode of Injection Location

Tags: java, bytecode, code-injection, opcode

I need to inject some bytecode into a method, but I'm a bit new to this.  I've gotten it to work before by simply finding the RETURN Opcode and injecting there, but my new need is more specific:

```
 public void onCollideWithPlayer(EntityPlayer par1EntityPlayer)
    {
        if (!this.worldObj.isRemote)
        {
            if (this.field_70532_c == 0 && par1EntityPlayer.xpCooldown == 0)
            {
                par1EntityPlayer.xpCooldown = 2;
                this.playSound("random.orb", 0.1F, 0.5F * ((this.rand.nextFloat() - this.rand.nextFloat()) * 0.7F + 1.8F));
                par1EntityPlayer.onItemPickup(this, 1);
                par1EntityPlayer.addExperience(this.xpValue);
                //NEED TO INJECT HERE
                this.setDead();
            }
        }
    }
```

I've commented where I need to inject the bytecode.  What Opcode should I be looking for for the injection?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `setDead` is a nonprivate virtual method, you'll want to look for the `invokevirtual` opcode*. However, since there are multiple method calls in the function, you'll need to disambiguate by function called, which means looking up the associated constant pool index. Hopefully whatever tool or framework you're using has helper code to do this for you.

If `setDead` is private, you'll want `invokespecial` instead. If for some reason it's static (yes you can call static methods via `this` if you want to), then you'll need to look for `invokestatic` instead.

Comment: And in case the caller is a `default` method, you have to look for `invokeinterface` instead. Thanks to Java 8, it could be all four types.